# multithread programming with pthread and operator new on c++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have class:

```
class AbstractTask {
public:
/* 
 some fields, methods
*/  
    AbstractTask(){   
        isCompletedFl=new bool;
        *isCompletedFl=false;    
    }
    ~AbstractTask(){      
        delete isCompletedFl;
    }
    void setTaskCompleted(){
        *isCompletedFl=true; 
    }
    bool isTaskCompleted(){
         return *isCompletedFl;
    }
private:   
    volatile bool *isCompletedFl;
};
```

In main function i writed (*task is a object of class AbstractTask):

```
/** some code */
while (flag){
     /** some code */
    if (task->isTaskCompleted()){
        /** some code */ 
    }
}
```

Method `setTaskCompleted()` called by only other threads.

This program work incorrectly in 50% cases - code inside if-block don't execute or something else... But program freezes.

If I change code in main function:

```
/** some code */
while (flag){
     /** some code */
    if (task->isTaskCompleted()){
         int *checkV=new int;
         *checkV=1;
         delete checkV;
    /** some code */
    }
}
```

the program works correctly always.

How is this possible? I compile program with g++ without any flags.
I need write this program for old compiler, and I can't use c++11.
If i rewrited class `AbstractTask` like this:

```
class AbstractTask {
public:
/* 
 some fields, methods
*/
    AbstractTask(){ 
        pthread_mutex_init(&mutex,NULL);
        isCompletedFl=new bool;
        *isCompletedFl=false;    
    }
    ~AbstractTask(){   
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);   
        delete isCompletedFl;
    }
    void setTaskCompleted(){
         pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
         *isCompletedFl=true; 
         pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex); 
    }
    bool isTaskCompleted(){
         pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
         bool tmp=*isCompletedFl;        
         pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);    
         return tmp;
    }
private:   
    bool *isCompletedFl;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
};
```

my program all the same freezes, and adding

```
int *checkV=new int;
*checkV=1;
delete checkV;
```

in loop in main-function does not give any effect.

Comment: `volatile` doesn't make anything thread-safe. Use a mutex.

Comment: I'd suggest you use C++11 threads. There you also find synchronization tools, which you need. As @πάνταῥεῖ said, volatile is useless for MT programming, forget about it.

Comment: please use pstack/gstack or similar command to see process stack trace. This can help in identifying where threads are stuck. I am assuming that you have initialized mutex somewhere in your code.

Comment: You need synchronization since otherwise there's no guarantee that changes made to memory in one thread will be visible in another thread. Maybe the `new` things served to flush caches.

Comment: I suspect thats not enough code to identify the problem. Why is "isCompletedFl" a pointer to a bool and not directly a bool. Where and when is that pointer initialized?